# How to implement keyword search?

Tags: mysql

I have an item database that I want to be able to search with pre-defined keywords.

What I have right now are three tables like this:

Items_tbl:

> item_idx, item (UNIQUE), description, etc.

Keyword_tbl:

> kw_idx, kw (UNIQUE), kw_description

Cross_tbl:

> item_idx, kw_idx.

I want to do the "and"-search...
Like...   Give me (distinct) every item that have the keywords "aquamarine", "blue", and "green".  i.e. "aquamarine" & "blue" & "green"...

Searching an "or"-search is quite simple, but I am stumped doing an "and" search like this...  In this ex. I want to find items with both "blue" and "green", but not items with just "green".

Comment: For now, you might have the time table for a MySQL based search, but for the future I'd consider attaching a search framework like Solr, Lucene, Xapian or other related software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   Items_tbl.*
FROM     Items_tbl
    JOIN Cross_tbl   USING (item_idx)
    JOIN Keyword_tbl USING (kw_idx)
WHERE    kw_description IN ('aquamarine','blue','green')
GROUP BY item_idx
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 3
```

This assumes that keywords can only be associated with items at most one time (i.e. a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(item_idx, kw_idx)` in `Cross_tbl`); if that is not the case, you will have to replace `COUNT(*)` with the less efficient `COUNT(DISTINCT kw_idx)`, or the even less efficient `COUNT(DISTINCT kw_description)` if the same keyword can appear multiple times in `Keyword_tbl` (i.e. no `UNIQUE` constraint on the `kw_description` column).

Answer (score 0):

Query your source table for each keyword.

`select * from YourTable where YourColumn like '%keyword%' and YourColumn like '%foo%';`

Comment: I must admit that I didn' understand that answer at all. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: I was assuming you would want "book" to also find the keywords "bookshelf" and "guestbook", hence the like-operator and the wildcards.